# IBAction sender type

Tags: ios, swift

what is the difference between （UIBarbuttonItem or other） and Any?

[image]

Thanks！

Comment: Read this excellent introduction by nhipster about [IBAction](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/)

Comment: Well, the obvious and only difference is the type of the parameter you get from the action method.

Comment: Basic difference is `UIBarButtonItem` tells that the sender object is always going to be `UIBarButtonItem`, so that you can be informed and be clear that the object is of specific type. Whereas `Any` means that the sender object can be anything and it is up to you to cast it to the type that is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is specific vs. unspecific type.

- Use the **specific** type if only this particular UI element is supposed to call the method and you need to process properties like `title` or `tag` of the passed `sender`.
- Use the **unspecific** type if the method can be called from different places with different sender types or if the `sender` parameter is not used at all.